# How to rotate a <div> 90 degrees?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` that I want to rotate 90 degrees:

```
<div id="container_2"></div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 524, accepted):

You need CSS to achieve this, e.g.:

```css
#container_2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Demo:

```css
#container_2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container_2"></div>
```

(There's 45 degrees rotation in the demo, so you can see the effect)

**Note:** The `-o-` and `-moz-` prefixes are [no longer relevant and probably not required](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). IE9 requires `-ms-` and Safari and the Android browser require `-webkit-`

---

**Update 2018:** Vendor prefixes are not needed anymore. Only `transform` is sufficient. (thanks @rinogo)

Comment: also, make sure its a block

Answer (score 32):

Use following in your CSS

```css
div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);   /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);   /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);   /* Opera */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Just as a suggestion to all future readers: always place the prefixed rules **before** the standards definition. In this case, all browser-prefixed rules should be before the `transform: rotate(90deg);` rule. The reason would be that typically, you want the standards to take precedence, and in CSS the last definition always wins.

Answer (score 18):

Use `transform: rotate(90deg)`:

```css
#container_2 {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: .5em;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    transition: .3s all;  /* rotate gradually instead of instantly */
}

#container_2:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* to support Safari and Android browser */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);      /* to support IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container_2">This box should be rotated 90&deg; on hover.</div>
```

Click "Run code snippet", then hover over the box to see the effect of the transform.

Realistically, no other prefixed entries are needed. See *[Can I use CSS3 Transforms?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)*

Comment: This would be better as a comment under an existing answer... or make an edit to an existing answer stating that the other prefixes are probably not needed. Having 3 pretty much exactly the same answers is unhelpful.

Comment: @Zaz how to keep the box rotated even after i unhover?

Comment: @ayushsharma: Use JS or see [Make CSS Hover state remain after “unhovering”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100235/make-css-hover-state-remain-after-unhovering):  One hack suggested there is `#element{transition: 9999999s}` (which makes the transition back to normal take forever) and `#element:hover{transition: .3s}` (or however long you want the rotation to take).

Answer (score 6):

you can use css3 property **writing-mode**
    writing-mode: tb-rl

[css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/writing-mode/)

[mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

Answer (score 6):

Use the css "rotate()" method:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div#rotate{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
normal div
</div>
<br>

<div id="rotate">
This div is rotated 90 degrees
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can add the following to a particular tag in CSS:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

In case of half rotation change `90` to `45`.