# How to make commandeButon to vertical align?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I would like to make primefaces commandButton to vertical align. 
how to set commandButton's css  in vertical align, as in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Related: [Using CSS to rotate an input's value 90 degrees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233341/how-can-i-rotate-an-html-div-to-90-degrees).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
transform: rotate(90deg) ;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
-o-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg) ;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/poselab/54XvF/

[CSS3 MAKER](http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transform.html) is a good tool to create your css transforms