# Making Portion of a linked div not a link

Tags: html, css

Site: http://tinyurl.com/x983asd93

Looking at the top right corner, the triangle banner.

Basically, I only want to link that portion of the triangle banner, so that the buttons under it can still be clicked. I don't want the entire div to be linked, but the triangle image is a transparent rectangle, with only the triangle filled. So I'm not sure how to only link that portion of the triangle.

Hopefully you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to acheive that with an image map.

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/

It does mean you'd need to use an img instead of having it as a background, however.

Comment: And when it scales down, such as for mobile devices, would the coords change or would they stay the same?

Comment: Also, when changing it to an img tag, I can't use no-repeat scroll right top transparent contain either... so this ruins my current design.

Comment: Ok - different tack; howabout a 45 deg. div. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233341/how-can-i-rotate-an-html-div-to-90-degrees

Comment: Rotating it does work, however then I have to apply margins to hack it into place. Upon resize, it doesn't stick to the size of the image and goes out of place.