# Triangle overlay in right corner css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I want to  create an overlay with css over one image like this:
[image]

but  I only do a square overlay like this:
[image]

how I can make the first shape with css ??

here is my code:

```
.card-img-overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0;
left: 150px;
padding: 1.25rem;
}
```

thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Use the rotation method as explained [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233341/how-can-i-rotate-an-html-div-90-degrees)

Comment: You can use plenty of things: From CSS `linear-gradient` background, CSS `:before` with border, CSS `transform` and `rotate`, CSS3 -`clip-path` and `polygon`,  painted `canvas` shape, SVG...  So many options - yet you tried none? Or did you? What was your google research and which one you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will go with a simple gradient and no need for any extra markup or the use of pseudo element:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(to top right, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 51%) 0 0/100% 200px no-repeat, 
  url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/) center/cover;
}
div {
 height:200px;
 text-align:right;
 color:#fff;
 padding:10px;
 font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How can we  place some text inside the RED area , If I add some more controls it looks like the shape is breaking

Answer (score 5):

[Check this out](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

```css
#triangle-topleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid #9020d1bb;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container #triangle-topleft,
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
  <div id="overlay">Microsoft</div>
</div>
```