# Web App Manifest Per Page Orientation

Tags: manifest.json, progressive-web-apps

In the web app manifest of a progressive web app, is it possible to set different orientations based on what page the user is viewing?

Here's what my `manifest.json` looks like:

```
{
    "dir": "ltr",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "name": "My Application",
    "scope": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "start_url": "start_page.aspx",
    "short_name": "My App",
    "theme_color": "transparent",
    "description": "My App Description",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "background_color": "#00A3CC",
    "related_applications": [],
    "prefer_related_applications": false,
    "icons": [
    {
        "src": "Images/Icon.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
        "src": "Images/Icon.png",
        "type": "image/png",
        "sizes": "512x512"
    }
    ]
}
```

The above manifest causes `https://example.com/start_page.aspx` and every other page to be displayed in portrait orientation when the app is installed. Is it possible to force `https://example.com/other_page.aspx` to be displayed in landscape orientation while keeping the rest of my site in portrait orientation?

Answer (score 0):

manifest.json - orientation is a static option for the entire application. You cant have per page/per module values.

You have two options to solve your issue.

1) Orient using CSS - Load the other_page.aspx inside a  in the current page(like SPA) and use [CSS as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14233398/1057093) to orient in landscape by shifting 90 degree.

2) Make your other_page.aspx as a separate app with a separate manifest.json with landscape orientation. You can do this only if this make sense to separate this as its a logically different module.